# Using For loop with a class object

Tags: python, class, for-loop

I am trying to iterate through a class object that contains 2 class objects within it and find a matching attribute using a for loop, the attribute here is "title" that has the value = "hello there", so asking for an input title then try to match it with a title within the 2 class objects , when i enter the correct title, i still get the error that says "Error: Please enter a valid book title" ..

```
import random
books = []
def random_title():

         title = 'hello there'
         return title 

class Books:

    def __init__(self, title =''):
        
        self.title = title

    def set_title(self, title = ''  ):
        self.title =  random_title()
        
    def get_title(self):
        return self.title
        
    def __getitem__(self, title):
        return self.title


class BookList(Books):
    def __init__(self):
        self.book_list = []

    def store_book(self, book):
        self.book_list.append(book)

    def search_book(self):
          search_method = input()
          while True:
            if search_method not in ['1']:
                  search_method = input()
            else:
                 search_method = int(search_method)
                 if search_method == 1:
                      book_title = input().title()
                      while True:
                        for item in self.book_list:
                         if book_title != item.title or book_title != "Back":
                            book_title = input('Error: Please enter a valid book title or "back" to go back to the main menu: ').title()
                         else:
                           if book_title == 'Back':
                               main()
                           else:
                              if book_title == item.title:
                                print(item)



    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.book_list[index]


def main():
      book1 = Books()
      book1.set_title()
      book2 = Books()
      book2.set_title()
      book_list = BookList()
      book_list.store_book(book1)
      book_list.store_book(book2)
      book_list.search_book()
main()
```

Comment: @Ethicist this is a sample code, the actually code has 4 search methods, so that list was supposed to have [1,2,3,4] , but i deleted them to reduce a smaller sample , you simply just enter 1 here to get the code working

Comment: That's because your loop is only checking the first book.  You need to scan through the entire list before you can definitively say the book is not present.  And please, God, remove the recursive call to `main()` inside that loop.  That is the wrong, wrong, wrong way to handle that.  If you have an error, then return an error code, and let the caller decide how to handle it.

Comment: `if book_title != item.title or book_title != "Back"` will always be true unless `item.title == "Back"`.

Comment: Note that you are inconsistent about whether `search_method` is a string or an integer.  That will cause you problems.

Comment: @TimRoberts nevermind that, i can handle it, the main issue here is the for loop that says : for item in self.book_list

Comment: @Samwise and your suggestion to fix it is ? i did use "and" operator and nothing changed

Comment: what's the point of all the `book_title != "Back":` and `book_title == "Back"` checks?  You could try offering additional information on what all parts of your code do if you expect serious help.

Comment: @Ethicist in case the user enters "back" , they are redirected to a main menu, sorry if it wasnt clear

Comment: Right.  So, check for that separately, and exit immediately.  Don't pollute your search with that extra clause.

Comment: @lucakramp there are a bunch of other things wrong with the code (as Tim called out in his answer); that was just the first bug to jump out at me.  I'd actually suggest you take a step back from this particular assignment/project and review earlier material, since having so many problems in one piece of code is usually an indication of having bitten off more than you can chew at once.

Answer (score -1):

This code does what you were trying to do.  I suggest you compare this to your own code to see where you went awry.

```
books = []

class Books:
    def __init__(self, title =''):
        self.title = title

    def set_title(self, title = ''  ):
        self.title = title

    def get_title(self):
        return self.title


class BookList(Books):
    def __init__(self):
        self.book_list = []

    def store_book(self, book):
        self.book_list.append(book)

    def search_book(self):
        while True:
            search_method = int(input('Method? '))
            if search_method in [1]:
                break
            print("try again")

        if search_method == 1:
            while True:
                book_title = input('Title? ')
                if book_title == "back":
                    return False

                for item in self.book_list:
                    if book_title == item.title:
                        print(item)
                        break
                else:
                    print('Error: Please enter a valid book title or "back" to go back to the main menu.')

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.book_list[index]

def main():
      book1 = Books('one')
      book2 = Books('two')
      book_list = BookList()
      book_list.store_book(book1)
      book_list.store_book(book2)
      book_list.search_book()
main()
```

There are some more significant design problems here.  The `BookList` class should not be doing any I/O.  It is a utility class.  The mainline code should ask for the search method and the book title, and then call methods in the `BookList` to do the search and return the found result.  Let the main code do any I/O that is needed.